# Convert Group ID into Name

Tags: process-builder, fields

Rookie here so please be patient...

My goal is to store the last queue a case owned by before being assigned by omni. I'm using a pb process to trigger on the agent work object. Currently I'm successfully saving the ID for the queue to a custom field on the case object using this AgentWork field.

[AgentWork].OriginalGroupId

This stores something like 00G1M0000063pO2AIU, I would like to convert the ID to the clean Queue Name. Is that possible?

My coding skills are limited so I would prefer not to deal with Apex unless I have to. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, any time you see a field that ends with "Id", and it references another object, you can replace it with `.Name` to get the name of the related record (or any other of these [Name fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_name.htm), such as `.Email`). So, in your case, you should be able to use:

```
[AgentWork].OriginalGroup.Name
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I knew it was something simple... unfortunately, still having some issues.
  
The process builder accepted [AgentWork].OriginalGroup.Name so it seems like it should work but when the case is assigned through omni nothing is written to my last case field.  

I know the process is firing because I have it saving the assignment time on the case as well. and that is working. When I switch back to [AgentWork].OriginalGroupID the ID works for the same cases coming out of the same queue.  

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.